Tkinter window opening alongside Pygame window
I am writing some python code that initially opens a TKinter window, when this is closed it should and does open a Pygame window. You can prompt the opening of another TKinter window alongside the Pygame one.
When this second Tkinter window opens, the Pygame window does not "pause" as intended.
threading.Thread(target=settings_).start()
    #the above fixes the crashes but I need the Pygame window to pause hence below code
    #settings_()
    is_open = "yes"
    while is_open == "yes":
        f = open("is_settings_open.txt", "r")
        is_open = str((f.read()))
        pygame.time.delay(10)
        # causes same issue


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It is not recommended to mix GUI frameworks for this exact reason. The internals of pygame and tkinter interact in unexpected and unpredictable ways. I recommend you stick to only 1 framework per project

Answering myself:
For intended results of the Pygame window being essentially unresponsive including not being able to close it whilst the tkinter window is open, I did not use pygame.time.display/wait or time.sleep as all of these caused crashes. I instead addedand is_open == "no" to all functionality checks (checks to see if buttons are pressed). I also added it here which prevents the window from closing:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if (event.type == pygame.QUIT  and is_open == "no"):
        running = False

